# failed to open stream

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5.3

Environment:

- Linux mint
- Lampp
- php 7 cli
- apache 2
- Laravel 5.3

I executed the following commands:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravelProject
php artisan serve
```

But I had this Warning:

> PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>       PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R username bootstrap/cache/
sudo chown -R dvuz stororage
```

or

Try this, you may not have installed any packages

```
$sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
$ sudo apt-get install libnet-libidn-perl 
$ sudo apt-get install php-all-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install php-cgi 
$ sudo apt-get install php-cli 
$ sudo apt-get install php-common 
$ sudo apt-get install php-curl 
$ sudo apt-get install php-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install php-gd 
$ sudo apt-get install php-gmp
```

After execute `composer install` in your project dir